# Intellij replace getClass() with ClassName.class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

Is there a way in an IntellJ Idea project that I can replace all calls to getClass() with the current class name + .class?

So for example replace:

```
class ClassName{
  public method(){
    Logger.logDebug(getClass(), "Some information")
  }
}
```

with

```
class ClassName{
  public method(){
    Logger.logDebug(ClassName.class, "Some information")
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a feature called structural search that you probably could use: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html

Comment: @Magnilex I know about the structurally search and replace, unfortunately, I am having difficulties creating the right templates.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please go through the link @Magnilex shared or the PDF at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/ssr.pdf and try out a few things and see if you face any issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this Structural Search template:

```
$This$.getClass()
```

Edit variables -> This -> Text/regexp: this, minimum count: 0, maximum count: 1

Replacement Template

```
$Clazz$.class
```

Edit variables -> Clazz -> Script text:

```
import com.intellij.psi.util.PsiTreeUtil;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiClass;
PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(__context__, PsiClass.class).getQualifiedName();
```

**UPD:**
JetBrains support:
This is currently not supported in the new Structural Search & Replace (SSR) dialog. It is possible to do this by going back to the old UI, here's how:

1. Invoke Help | Find Action... (Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+A)
2. Type Registry and invoke the Registry... action
3. Remove the check mark for the ssr.use.new.search.dialog key and close the dialog

Now when you invoke SSR, you're back to the old dialog and can use replacement variables again. Restoring replacement variables for the new SSR dialog is planned for version 2019.2, but no guarantee.

Comment: Exactly..., but, how are we supposed to find such an answer? Ow, wait, right, .... just ask Stack Overflow... Many thanks komelgman.

Comment: Does this still work in IntelliJ 2018.x ? It always shows the error message ***"Malformed replacement pattern"*** when the replacement variables are not the same as the search variables.

Comment: Vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204454 bug for speedup fixing it.